# How to make a pipeline to group and count in mongodb?

Tags: arrays, database, mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

I have a document similar like this in mongodb with collection name: "movie" :-

```
collection = movie

[{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "573a1390f29313caabcd446f"
  },

  "imdb": {
    "rating": 6.6,
    "votes": 1375,
    "id": 832
  },

 "review": {
    "rating": 6.6,
    "votes": 1375,
    "id": 832
  }

},

{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "573a1390f29313caabcd45f7"
  },

  "imdb": {
    "rating": 4.6,
    "votes": 1375,
    "id": 832
  },

 "review": {
    "rating": 8,
    "votes": 432,
    "id": 322
  }

}]
```

How can I make a pipeline to group and count the number of based on the
average of rating in review?

Comment: Can you revise the attached document? It is not a valid JSON/BSON documents. And define the definition of average rating.

Comment: @YongShun yes done

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: @nimrodserok plz check now

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$facet` and `$bucket` for that:

```
db.movie.aggregate( [
  {
    $facet: {
      "review_rating": [
        {
            $bucket: {
                  groupBy: "$review.rating",                    
                  boundaries: [0, 3, 5, 10], // Boundaries for the buckets
                  default: "Other",                             // In case some data do not fall into a bucket
                  output: {                                     // Output for each bucket
                      "count": { $sum: 1 }
            }
        }
      }
      ],
      "imbd_rating": [
        {
            $bucket: {
                groupBy: "$imdb.rating",                    
                boundaries: [0, 3, 5, 10], // Boundaries for the buckets
                default: "Other",                             // In case some data do not fall into a bucket
                output: {                                     // Output for each bucket
                   "count": { $sum: 1 }
                }
            }
      }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

That should count the number of elements of each bucket for both `review.rating` and `imdb.rating`.
If you need more information, visit [`$facet in MongoDB Docs`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/).

Comment: It is showing the following error: Command failed with error 16412 (Location16412): 'FieldPath field names may not contain '.'. Consider using $getField or $setField.' on server localhost:27017. The full response is {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "FieldPath field names may not contain '.'. Consider using $getField or $setField.", "code": 16412, "codeName": "Location16412"}